# Tensorflow paradox

Tags: windows-10, python3

It seems I have tensorflow installed yet I cannot import it.

Here,

```
C:\ pip install tensorflow 
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in C:\ #location
```

but

`>>> import tensorflow as tf
Trackback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow"`

Comment: Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a manual install of TensorFlow as in:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/

then test if it works in Python, and then if successful direct R to use that Python installation...

Comment: Tried that, It returns 'Requirement already satisfied'

Comment: Is python up to date?

Comment: I've python 3.6.3.